# Change the height of UISegmentedControl in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Problem: How to change the height of the UISegmentedControl in iOS?

After Searching, I got the following answers:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame= segmentedControl.frame;
    [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 200.0, 50.0)];
}
```

But this resets the height of the control to default if I select any option of the segmented control in iOS 7

Comment: **Solution:** With the above code, also uncheck the **"Use Auto Layout"** property in the File Inspector of that segmented control

Comment: Just so you know, unchecking "Use Auto Layout" disables auto layout for the whole storyboard, not just for the individual control.

Comment: Another option from the story board is to 'Clear Constraints' on that element.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have autolayout, set the constraints of the UISegmentedControl. Please see pic of where's easiest to set this, make sure width and height are ticked, plus vertical and horizontal space constraints (select where lines that are deep orange in pic).

[image]

Now that you have this, control-drag the constraint that sets the height of the segmented control to your header file and name it something like `segmentedControlHeightConstraint`.

Once you have done that, within your viewDidLoad in your view controller implementation file add this code

```
self.segmentedControlHeightConstraint.constant = 50; // or whatever height you wish
```

This is the best way using auto layout to set the height for this.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Jeely! How it is different from if I select the control (or double click the control) and go to Editor -> Pin -> Height and change the height from there? Then I do not have to write anything in the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:segmentContl
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:18]];
```

"change constant value for changing height"

Answer (score -2):

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mySegmentedControl
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:nil
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                         multiplier:1 
                                         constant:fNewHeight];
    [mySegmentedControl addConstraint:constraint];
```

Comment: this will work fine for iOS 7.0 upwards ,most of the scenarios Autolayout is always better than frames